# npm -version displays nothing

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, windows-xp

I am new to NodeJS and I just downloaded and installed nodeJS in my windows XP machine. However, after installing whatever npm command I have given, it  displays nothing. It just displays the command prompt. See below the response in command prompt.

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js  and npm.

C:\Documents and Settings\User>npm -version

C:\Documents and Settings\User>

Being new to nodejs I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Can any one help me with this issue?

Thanks,

Kishore

Comment: try npm --version ;P
(You need two dashes)

Comment: I'm on Linux with npm 2.5.0, and I get a version number with `-v`, `--version`, *and* `-version`. Idk if the OS makes a difference here, but I would think not.

Comment: npm --version did not make any difference.

Comment: @BenA. I get my npm version just fine with one dash (works with two too though). Did you try restarting cmd?

Comment: I have restarted even my machine

Comment: @KishoreRamakrishnan Do other commands work, like `npm list`? What version did you download and install (I presume from nodejs.org)?

Comment: I have installed nodejs v0.12.0. "npm list" got same response. Displays nothing.